# Can an html label tag have more than one "for" attribute?

Tags: html

I want to allow one `<label>` tag to be associated with two `<input>` fields, in order to associate an `<input type="text">` value & an a.m./p.m. radio button with the same label. Is it possible to feed `<label>` two `for=""` values, or will I just have to "fudge" it with styling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The short answer would be : no you can't.

Comment: Elements can not have more than one of any attribute of the same name.